# Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: android, eclipse

I am currently trying to learn how to to write Android programs. I just finish reading the book "The Android Developer's Cookbook Building Applications with the Android SDK". I tried to write the following code:

```
Package src.com.cookbook.BlueToothSample;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class BlueToothExampleActivity extends Activity
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // button
            Button startBTButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Start_BT);
            startBTButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {



               @Override
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 startBlueTooth();              
               }

            });

        }

        private void startBlueTooth()
        {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter
            .ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        }

        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
              {
            String acton = intent.getAction();
            //When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(
                        BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.v("BlueTooth Testing", device.getName() + '\n'
                        + device.getAddress());
            }


            }


        };

      // Register the BroadcastReceiver
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
         registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
         myBluetooth.startDiscover();

    }
```

I am getting the following error: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody.
I thought I had all the bracket line up. Also after reading this forum I am going to purchase the book "Professional Android Application Developer". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of the error message, but the first word in your code should be `package`, not `Package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
     myBluetooth.startDiscover();
```

Must appear inside a constructor or a method. At a quick glance, that's all I saw was wrong, but no promises there's nothing more.

EDIT:

A method is probably the only thing that makes sense here actually, my bad.

EDIT:

Also the package thing mentioned in the comments... good catch @Ted

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid java syntax.

You can't do this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
 // Code here
}
```

nor this in the class directly

```
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
     myBluetooth.startDiscover();
```

Comment: Aside from needing a terminating `;` (which OP's code has), why can't assignment to `mReceiver` be done that way?

Answer (score 0):

You have registered broadcastereceiver in the wrong place so the comes place

```
  // Register the BroadcastReceiver
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
     myBluetooth.startDiscover();
```

in oncreate()